# Can I create more columns in the array 2D?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create 2 cells in the first array, but in the second array, I want to have 4 cells.

Is that possible in Java and is it logical?

Example:

```
public void stack(){
    int a[][] = {{2,5234},{5,33,345,45}};
}
```

Comment: Can i create more  Cells in the second array (in the array 2D)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible:

```
int[][] a = new int[2][];
a[0] = {2, 5234};
a[1] = {5, 33, 345, 45};
```

Or if you want to inline the entire definition:

```
int[][] a = new int[][]{{2, 5234}, {5, 33, 345, 45}};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is known as a "jagged array." If you wanted to declare the sizes of these, you could start off with the 2D array declaration:

```
int[][] a = new int[2][];
```

and then you can make the length whatever you please

```
a[0] = new int[2];
a[1] = new int[4];
```

Essentially the second dimensions of the arrays are arrays themselves. You can write explicitly what you want as:

```
a[0] = [2, 5234];
a[1] = [5, 33, 345, 45];
```

And furthermore, you can access the length of the second dimensions with:

```
int lengthOne = a[0].length;
int lengthTwo = a[1].length;
```

Is it logical? Absolutely. Jagged arrays are highly useful for things which don't fit the classic table format such as recording temperatures. This could be recorded as (for example):

```
double[][] temperatures = new double[12][];
```

Where there are 12 months in a year and:

```
temperatures[0] = new double[31];
```

January has 31 days.

Comment: wooow ! thank you man for this amazing explication i want to give you+1 but i have less than 15 reputation xD .thank you again  :D